# Classifier-only pipelines in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

While exploring pipelines in `sklearn`, I noticed the `Pipeline` class currently does not support building classifier-only pipelines.

To provide more clarity, what I need to do is something like this:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

pipeline = Pipeline(
    ('logreg', LogisticRegression()),
    ('random_clf', RandomForestClassifier()))
```

The above raises the error:

```
TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform.
  "RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
            warm_start=False)"
  (type <class 'sklearn.ensemble.forest.RandomForestClassifier'>) doesn't
```

Is this a design decision?

Is there a way to do this? I stumbled across `imblearn'`s `Pipeline` class [here](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline) but that doesn't seem to do what I want either.

Comment: What is your use case? What do you want to pass to second estimator in place of `X` and `y`? LR dont have `transform()` method to change the data. Explain in detail what you want to do?

Comment: If your current example is your use case, then sklearn is protecting you from yourself. It does not make much sense to chain to classifiers together- what would you be hoping to achieve? Are you trying to combine their decisions together? if so, have a look at `VotingClassifier`